# Split daynames with start - end time from a string to put in a mysql database

Tags: php, string, date, split

I got from my database one varchar string like this:

```
MO:8:00AM-10:00PM
TH:8:00AM-7:00PM
WE:1:00PM-6:00PM
TH:8:00AM-10:00PM
```

Now i want to split the whole thing for one the daynames and the start and end times in time tables.
On the site i would like to know when the server's times is in range of the given times in the database.

How to split these strings into columns daynames | starttime | endtime ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here it is. The info you need parsed out will be nice and neat in the variables ending in `_column`. You'll need to put them in the database during the loop.

```
$string = "MO:8:00AM-10:00PM TH:8:00AM-7:00PM WE:1:00PM-6:00PM TH:8:00AM-10:00PM";
$pieces = explode(" ", $string);
foreach($pieces as $piece) {
    $day = explode(":", $piece, 2);
    $start = explode("-", $day[1], 2);
    $end = $start[1];


    $dayname_column = $day[0];
    $starttime_column = $start[0];
    $endtime_column = $end;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a million ways to do that. Here is a way that builds an array of line and where each line is processed to create an array with Day, Start time, End time using `array_map` and a callback function:

```
$data = <<<EOD
MO:8:00AM-10:00PM
TH:8:00AM-7:00PM
WE:1:00PM-6:00PM
TH:8:00AM-10:00PM
EOD;

$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $data);

$result = array_map(function ($item) { $tmp = explode('-', substr($item,3));
                                       array_unshift($tmp, substr($item,0,2));
                                       return $tmp; },
                    $lines);

print_r($result);
```

Comment: the original code he posted, which you edited, was delineated with spaces... not line breaks. Why not use his original data?

Comment: @bennett_an: no, the original code was delineated with line breaks too. The OP didn't well format his post (The line breaks was not visible)

Comment: oh, ok sorry, my mistake